# Is there a Java/ImageIO JBIG2 image writer?

Tags: java

I need to write images in the JBIG2 image format using Java/ImageIO.

I found the [levigo/jbig2-imageio](https://github.com/levigo/jbig2-imageio) library providing a JBIG2 reader allowing to read JBIG2 images using ImageIO, but I was unable to find a library providing a JBIG2 Image writer.

Does anybody know if there is an existing library or solution allowing to encode JBIG2 images using java ?

Comment: If you don't find one, I am interested in creating one, to become part of the [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) project. But as this is a non-trivial task, some kind of funding/sponsorship must be worked out.